# Daylight savings time has changed all of my iCal events?

Tags: calendar.app

Since Daylight savings time day, events that were already in my iCal are now off by one hour.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix it by doing the following:

1. Open the Settings on your iPhone
2. Select "Mail, Contacts, Calendars"
3. Scroll down to the Calendars section
4. Select "Time Zone Support"
5. Turn on Time Zone support

Or maybe you want to turn time zone support off? It's a little confusing. Here's what Apple says:

When Time Zone Support is on, Calendar displays event dates and times in the time zone set for your calendars. When Time Zone Support is off, Calendar displays events in the time zone of your current location.